# installing pythonnet or pywin32 in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install pywin32 and/or pythonnet in Windows 10 WSL.

When I run "pip install pythonnet", I get an error message saying "Failed building wheel for pythonnet".

Attempts at installing pywin32 is similarly unsuccessful.

Any suggestions on how to successfully install either?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

and try again.